# How to tell an instance of firefox to use eth0 instead of tun0 while OpenVPN is running and connected to a VPN server?

Tags: linux, firefox, vpn, openvpn

sometimes I need to connect to websites without passing through VPN, is it possible to open an instance of Firefox and tell it to use the plain `eth0` interface instead of the tun0 ?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with iptables a while back. The main difference between your goal, and my project, was that I was attempting to redirect all traffic incoming from the network to tun0. No changes to firefox required. The gist of it is this:

1. A custom entry in `rt_tables` is created to handle certain packets
2. All packets destined for port 80 or a specific IP are given a mark
3. All packets matching the mark in step 2 get passed to the rt_table specified in step 1.
4. The packets in the new `rt_tables` needs to have a different gateway than the rest - the IP of eth0

I found some old code of mine that should work for you either as it is, or with minor modifications. This is a slightly modified set of the code that I used to run on my gateway:

```
# Create the new custom router table
echo 201 CustomRouter >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# Mark the desired packets for special treatment
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 123.123.123.123 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 123.123.123.123 -j MARK --set-mark 2

# Assign marked packets to CustomRouter
ip rule add fwmark 2 table CustomRouter

# Set the gateway
ip route add default via 192.168.0.123 dev eth0 table ClientRouter
```

The above presumes that `123.123.123.123` is the IP of the website you want via eth0, and `192.168.0.123` is the IP of `eth0`. Modify the two lines with that IP to match whatever you want, be it everything on port 80, or just specific one IP. the `123.123.123.123` is just a bogus IP I used for testing this.

Note that the line that creates `CustomRouter` in `rt_tables` doesn't have to be executed every time. The perl scrip from which I extracted this has a check to see if it's already there, so I believe it may only have to be done once, or possibly once every boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add routes for any websites you want to pass via eth0 like this:

```
ip route add websiteIP via gatewayIP dev eth0
```

Here, you add the IP address of the website you want to visit at `websiteIP`, and add your normal gateway IP at `gatewayIP`.

Comment: what is gateway IP ?

Comment: It is the IP address of your normal router. You can see it with `ip route show` command as the default gateway when you are not connected to VPN.

Answer (score 0):

network rules with ip route and iptables cannot use the program name as a criteria

If you need to route traffic to the other interface only for firefox and not for any request to a port 80, you could use network namespaces on newest kernels. They limit which system resources are available for a process ("ip netns")

Here is an introduction with a similar example:

http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/an-introduction-to-network-namespaces/